# Are there examples of Apis mellifera of different colors?

Tags: genetics, entomology, pigmentation

Re: my previous [species-identification](/questions/tagged/species-identification) question,  [What species is this gray bee?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/79767/what-species-is-this-gray-bee) I'm still curious: Are there any recorded/reported cases of either albino *Apis mellifera*, or at least with substantially different pigmentation/color? Is it possible that only part of a colony gets this trait?

Comment: In conjunction with your other question, I wanted to let you know that there is a huge variety of species of bees found in the wild, especially in more rural areas. See this link for example that has some bee genera found in Chile: https://www.yorku.ca/bugsrus/resources/galleries/bgoc I think your picture with that earlier question is too unclear to answer but I think the simplest answer is that you have found a bee of a species that is not *Apis mellifera*.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thanks! I really appreciate any info. If you could write that as an answer to the original question, I'd be grateful

Comment: I don't think it could really serve as an answer because your picture is too unclear to identify, and just providing a link to the first Google result for "bee species Chile" is not really enough research effort to warrant an answer, just wanted to help point you in the right direction for the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been reading a little more, and found a partial answer.

Not sure about albinoes, but Wikipedia lists a few different colors, arguably *substantially* different:

Under *Apis mellifera* subsp. [*ligustica*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_bee) (the Italian honeybee),

- Leather
- Bright yellow (golden)
- Very pale yellow

Under *Apis mellifera [caucasia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caucasian_honey_bee)* (Caucasian honeybee),

- Dark with brown spots at times

In fact, both photos below are reported as *Apis mellifera*, [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Honeybee_-_Balar%C4%B1s%C4%B1_01.jpg) and [here](https://bugguide.net/node/view/93666) respectively.
[image]
[image]